# DAX Calculated Relationship

Tags: filter, dax, ssas-tabular

- Month, MyMeasure
- Nov-15, 150
- Dec-15, 150
- Jan-16, 200
- Feb-16, 200 -- projections into the future not desired
- Mar-16, 200 -- projections into the future not desired
- Apr-16, 200 -- projections into the future not desired

I have a measure which uses an ALL function to remove the relationship to the date table and calculate a distinctcount in a modified context. Which is great but now the measure extends into the future until the end of the date table.

I need to apply another filter after the first calculation:

If calendar[date] < today() 
then MyMeasure 
ELSE blank

or maybe something using LOOKUPVALUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CALCULATE(
    [<measure>]
    ,FILTER(
        ALL( 'DimDate' )
        ,'DimDate'[Date] <= TODAY()
    )
)
```